# Appropriate attire for interview at tech company

Tags: interviewing

I'm concerned about appropriate attire for a female interviewing for a creative marketing position within a relatively new tech company.  I don't want to appear overdressed or like I won't fit into the company but want to be professional and show proper amount of respect for the interviewer, company, job and myself.

Comment: @MaskedMan I don't think it is a duplicate, as this question asks about a female, while the question you link seems to be tailored to male applicants. I there is a significant difference.

Comment: The basic advice remains the same. Business casual or better as baseline assumption; business formal is unlikely to hurt (at worst it comes across as "I really want this job"),and if you want a real answer call HR or your prospective boss's Administrative Assistant and ask them what's typical -- then consider going up a half-step from there.

Comment: @Bernhard I see no evidence that the question is tailored to men, it is about as gender-neutral as it can get. Some of the answers even explicitly mention what women should wear.

Answer (score -2):

At the tech company, they will be wearing a Mickey Mouse or Snoopy pull over, jeans and trainers. That does not mean that you can wear the same at the interview.

Tips: avoid skirts and heels, and go for a more "masculine" look. Trousers and flat shoes will let you still look formal and professional.

The shoes need to be black and the suit need to be three pieces. Slightly overdressed is better than the other way round.

Wear neutral colors. A gray suit and a black thin wool pull-over will be perfect. If it's too hot for a pull-over, wear a white or blue shirt. The advice above about looking less "girly" still applies.

Comment: Really?  I work in tech and I often wear a skirt and heels to interviews :)

Comment: A three piece suit is more than a little overdressed, unless you are interviewing for a senior management position and even then, likely too much.

Comment: Suggesting that a woman needs to dress like a man to get a job is demeaning to all of the well qualified women who already work in tech.  Gender shouldn't be part of the equation and this suggestion goes in the opposite direction.

Comment: @cdkMoose: suggesting that women are being discriminated by their appearance even if well-qualified is demeaning to the people doing the hiring, not to the women.

Comment: @QuoraFeans, it also suggests that is how the current women in tech got there.

Comment: This is for a creative marketing position, not a technical position. The audience is very different. Technical jobs tend to be staffed by men, but from my own work experience, the opposite is true for marketing. So trying to look less "girly" is not only bad advice in general, but utterly useless in this situation.